# CSS overflow bug on Mobile

Tags: css

I'm using the Gridless CSS Framework's html/body tags as wrappers; which works great!

I'm un-role'n my site; the role main attribute would span across the page on desktop/mobile.  But the new heading ID needs the width/margin increased and the overflow is not hidden on mobile.  Any ideas?

```
article[role="main"] #heading,article header#heading{clear:both;overflow:hidden;z-index:333;position:relative;width:112%!important;height:auto;margin:0 -6% 1% -6%;padding:2% 2% 2% 2%;text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Is this even on topic?

Comment: Questions regarding [coding](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are unfortunately considered off-topic for this site. I'd migrate this to Stack Overflow, but it looks like you already solved it yourself - thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it. Changed the `width` from 112% to 111.5%

The bug was w/

```
.msg {
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:333;
    position:relative;
    width:111.5%!important;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 -6% 1% -6%;
    padding:2% 2% 2% 2%;
    text-align:center;
}
```